# AJAX not rendering on django template

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

So I am trying to render some text dynamically on a webpage using AJAX. I created an empty div and attempted to fill it with some data but it renders nothing. Firstly, my question is how do I pass extra data to the AJAX call? Below is the HTML

```
<div>
{% for user in searched_users %}
<p>{{ user.user.username }}</p>
</div>
<div id = "links">
 <a id = "follow" href="{% url 'add' name=user.user.username %}">Follow</a> <a id="unfollow" href="{% 
url 'unfollow' name=user.user.username %}">Unfollow</a> <a href = "{% url 'match' 
 name=user.user.username %}">Perform Match?</a>
 </div>

 <div id = "display">
  </div>

 {% endfor %}

 <script>

 element = document.getElementById("follow");
  target_element = document.getElementById("display");
 data = user.user.username
 element.onclick = () =>{
 $.ajax({
  url : "/follow/",
  data : data,
  success: display
  }

  )};

 function display (data) {
      if (data) {
          console.log(data);
          // Add the http response to element
          target_element.innerHTML = data;
      }}
  </script>
  {% endblock %}
```

it has a couple of `href-s` used for following, unfollowing a user. When a user clicks on the `follow` href, I want to display the `HTTPresponse` of this view.

```
 def follow(request, name):
    sender = User.objects.get(username = request.session["username"]).userprofile
    display = User.objects.get(username=name)
    receiver = User.objects.get(username= name).userprofile
    if receiver not in sender.get_friends() and sender != receiver:
        relationship = Relationship.objects.get_or_create(
        from_person=sender,
        to_person=receiver,
        status = 1
        )
    return HttpResponse (f" added {display.username}")
    elif sender == receiver:
       raise ValidationError("Can't follow yourself")
    else:
         return HttpResponse("Already following")
```

One probable cause of failure is the extra argument, `name` not being passed into the AJAX call. How do I pass it to the AJAX call? Can I use `user.user.username` in AJAX? Doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Did you tried below answer ?

Answer (score 0):

In your html code you have repeated `ids` so first change them to `class` . I am considering you are using jquery because you have `$.ajax` . So, now whenever your `follow` element is clicked use `.data("name")` to get `username` which is set as data-attribute in your `a` tag(added by me) .

Then , pass this to your backend code i.e : `data : {"username":your_value}` . Now , there can be mutliple `display` divs because its under `for-loop` so you need to display result only to particular `display` div where `follow` element is clicked so use `.closest(".links").next().text("mesage return from ajax")`.

You **html** will look like below  :

```
<div>
{% for user in searched_users %}
<p>{{ user.user.username }}</p>
<!--aded class-->
<div class = "links">
<!--added data attr-->
 <a class="follow" href="{% url 'add' name=user.user.username %}" data-name="{{ user.user.username }}">Follow</a> <a class="unfollow" href="{% 
url 'unfollow' name=user.user.username %}">Unfollow</a> <a href = "{% url 'match' 
 name=user.user.username %}">Perform Match?</a>
 </div>
 <div class = "display">
  </div>
 {% endfor %}
</div>
```

***Demo Code***  :

```js
$(".follow").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault() //to prevent default redirect
  var username = $(this).data("name")
  console.log(username)
  var selector = $(this).closest(".links").next() //get display div
  /* $.ajax({
     url: "/follow/",
     data: {
       "name": username //pass data here
     },
     success: function(data) {
       if (data) {
         console.log(data);*/
  // Add the http response to element
  selector.text("Ok ok "); //use data
  /* }
    }
  })*/
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

  <p>Abcd</p>

  <div class="links">
    <!--use attr here-->
    <a class="follow" data-name="Abcd" href="{% url 'add' name=user.user.username %}">Follow</a> <a class="unfollow" href="{% 
url 'unfollow' name=user.user.username %}">Unfollow</a> <a href="{% url 'match' 
 name=user.user.username %}">Perform Match?</a>
  </div>

  <div class="display"></div>

  <p>Abcds</p>

  <div class="links">
    <a class="follow" data-name="Abcds" href="{% url 'add' name=user.user.username %}">Follow</a> <a class="unfollow" href="{% 
url 'unfollow' name=user.user.username %}">Unfollow</a> <a href="{% url 'match' 
 name=user.user.username %}">Perform Match?</a>
  </div>

  <div class="display">
  </div>
</div>
```